# Update HTML block content via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, swig-template

I have a main `index.html` file and want to update only a certain block of that template via ajax.

As, I am already using `swig` on server side I decided to leverage that on my client side also.

I have a below ajax call and on success I want to update an HTML block.

```
$(function(){

    $('#category_nav').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var obj = {};
        obj.cgid = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: obj,
            url : '/SearchShow',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);

            },
            error : function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML snippet of `index.html`

```
           <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
           {% for product in products %}
                 <div class="view view-first">
                      <a href="{{product.link}}">
                       <div class="inner_content clearfix">
                        <div class="product_image">
                            <img src="{{product.imageSrc}}" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                            <div class="product_container">
                               <div class="cart-left">
                                 <p class="title">{{product.name}}</p>
                               </div>
                               <div class="price">{{product.price}}</div>
                               <div class="clearfix"></div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                     </a>
                   </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

`router`

```
app.get('/SearchShow', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.query);

    var cgid =  req.query.cgid;
    console.log("cgid: " + cgid);
    category.getProductsAssignedToCategory(cgid, function(productHits){
        res.send({
            "products" : productHits
        });
    });
});
```

On server side I use `res.render` to render the HTML but I couldn't find a way to update only a particular section of template via ajax & using swig template engine

Comment: Rather than downvoting, please also add a comment why you are downvoting. So, that question can be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the existing content, and then re-render using jQuery in the jQuery AJAX callback. Something like..

```
success : function(data) {
              $('#productName').empty();
              $('#productName').append(data.name);
          }
```

taking into account `<p>` id is *productName*:

```
<p id="productName" class="title">{{product.name}}</p>
```

I don't know how you do the update the tag `{% for product in products %}`, but i suggest you to see the generated html and re-render the content.